# Django authentication function returning None even though user exists

Tags: python, django, authentication

When ever i try to authenticate a user in django it returns None even though user exists. my code:

Login function:

```
def login_(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        username = request.POST["name"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("index")
        else:
            return error.error("102", "username or password is invalid!", request)
    else:
        return render(request, "login.html")
```

login.html:

```
{% extends 'template.html' %} 

{% block body %} 
<section class="bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-900">
    <div class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center px-6 py-8 mx-auto md:h-screen lg:py-0">
        <div class="w-full bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:border md:mt-0 sm:max-w-md xl:p-0 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
            <div class="p-6 space-y-4 md:space-y-6 sm:p-8">
                <h1 class="text-xl font-bold leading-tight tracking-tight text-gray-900 md:text-2xl dark:text-white">
                    Sign in to your account
                </h1>

                <form class="space-y-4 md:space-y-6" action="/login" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div>
                        <label for="name" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Your Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" placeholder="name..." required="">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="password" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="••••••••" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" required="">
                    </div>                    
                </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="w-full text-white bg-blue-600 mb-2 hover:bg-primary-700 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-primary-300 font-medium text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-primary-600 dark:hover:bg-primary-700 dark:focus:ring-primary-800">Sign in</button>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>
{% endblock %}
```

I tried replacing the authenticate function in the login function with

```
User.objects.get(username=username, password="I hard coded the hash from the database here")
```

When i tried this it worked . im am lost